# Swift Core Data for both Models and Data storage Engine

Tags: swift, core-data, database-design, model

I'm currently new to Swift and am trying to learn a little more about Core Data. Perhaps it has to do with Database Design or it has to do with Entity Creation.

I decided to start with a simple ToDo app, where a user can save each task. I learned quickly that Core Data is great for this, as every time I save or fetch the data it is saved in some "background database"? or something..

I then wanted to develop something that came with a predefined list of tasks that a user may have to complete, and allow the user to "activate" various tasks. For example: the user can find a tableview of predefined tasks: Task A, Task B, Task C, etc... and then swipe to add Task B to an array of their active tasks in another view.

What is the best practice for something like this? Should I create two separate but identical objects in Core Data? Should I create a MyTaskManager entity which has a to-many relationship with Tasks and save it to Core Data or User Defaults? Should I not be using Core Data for either of these classes? I'm fairly confused.

Thanks for your help, in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a field in the Task Core Data Object named something like „isUserTask“ or „isActiveTask“.

In the other table or collection you show only the Task Objects where „isUserTask“ or „isActiveTask“ is true.